# Mixing Elasticsearch minor versions in cluster nodes and clients - supported or not?

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to find out about the details of using Elasticsearch Java clients with a different minor version than is used within the cluster, I find different partial answers, see right below.

My question is:
When running an Elasticsearch cluster with version x.y : is it supported (generally ok/ not recommended/ totally forbidden) to use a client with version x.z ?  Is the answer different for node vs transport clients?

Thanks!

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html :
"Please note that you are **encouraged to use the same version on client and cluster sides**. You may hit some incompatibility issues **when mixing major versions**."

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html :
"The Java client **must be from the same version of Elasticsearch as the nodes**; otherwise, they may not be able to understand each other."

Comment: The general advice is to use the same version everywhere. ES nodes communicate with each other and if something changed in this communication protocol then you get unpredictable behavior. Always try to use the same ES version everywhere no matter if it's between nodes in the cluster, client nodes, java client etc.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for your comment. I'm aware that using the same version everywhere is the safest path. But in practical scenarios, this often comes with a cost, right? That's why, if there's a guarantee that clients can have minor versions different from the cluster's, it would be very valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

We're currently in that scenario, a 15 node cluster, 10 data nodes. One master and one data node are on 2.3.3, the rest on 2.3.2.
All the new indexes created since this partial upgrade have replicas which refuse to be assigned, effectively preventing us to finish the upgrade (cluster status is always yellow, but we're waiting the status to be back to green before continuing the rolling restart)

So yeah, I think they should have used a different wording here. Something like "DON'T DO IT", not "You maybe shouldn't do it"....